# How to scale a JFrame around a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, pong

I try to programm the game PONG.

My Problem: I use the JPanel as the "matchfield" with size (1000;600). But when I add the JPanel to the JFrame with setSize(dimension of the matchfield) i have a problem with the right and the lower border. 
It seems like the the JFrame gets the size (1000;600) and the JPanel gets smaller.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Use `JFrame#pack`, it will pack the window around the contents, this assumes you're components are providing appropriate sizing hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JPanel's size should be determined by its preferred size, not its size.  The easiest way to do this is by calling `setPreferredSize(...)` on it, but that allows other code to change its preferred size, and so the safest way is to override its `public Dimension getPreferredSize()` method. The JFrame will then naturally size itself correctly if the JPanel is added to the JFrame's BorderLayout-using contentPane, and then you call `pack()` on the JFrame after adding the JPanel and before displaying it.

For example:

```
public class MyJPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final int PREF_W = 1000;
    private static final int PREF_H = 600;

    public MyJPanel() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // to make smooth graphics
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; 
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // do your drawing here
    }

    // size the JPanel correctly
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MyJPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```